# C - read() method buffer

Tags: c, linux

Imagine that I use the C function `read()` to read for example 100 bytes from a file on my hard disk.

If I read 100 bytes now, and a few instructions later I try to read another 50 bytes from the same file, this function will access directly the hard disk again or the OS will put the file in memory (RAM) and this function will read those 50 bytes directly from the RAM?

What I mean here is, on the first access the OS will load a whole memory page from that file into the RAM or will only load what I ask?

And if I use `fread()` instead of `read()` will the result be the same?

Comment: It depends on whether the 50 bytes are in the same disk block as the first 100 bytes.

Comment: @Barmar It means that the read() function will load a whole memory page instead of that 100bytes only, right?

Comment: It also depends on if the filesystem is cached, some do read parts into memory, think of RAMDisk...

Comment: Disk I/O is in units of disk blocks. It can't read just 100 bytes.

Comment: Linux will try to cache the file in the kernel with block-size granularity (run `blockdev  --getbsz /dev/your_filesysteem` to get your block size).
Assuming it's something like 4KiB, the second read will likely be cached in the kernel's memory.

`fread` will usually call `read` with 4KiB-8KiB as the size argument and serve subsequent request from the associated FILE buffer. This should be more efficient than relying on the kernel's buffers.

Comment: There is caching at the OS level, and there is caching at the language level. `fread` provides the latter, ensuring that some buffering is happening.

Comment: Curious, why does "load a whole memory page from that file into the RAM or will only load what I ask" make a difference?  Is there a higher level concern that applies?

Comment: `fread`, a c runtime function that invokes the os-level `read` call, will often have its own lookahead buffering

Comment: The kernel buffers are also shared across processes. If some *other* process reads the same block of the file as you try to read soon after, your read will get it from the kernel's buffer cache instead of going to disk.

Comment: There are also layers of caching below the OS in the storage system (RAID controller, disk, etc.). Disk I/O is the slowest thing inside the computer, so you want as many opportunities to avoid it as possible.